# Python function not returning correct output

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Trying to use python to change the value associated to a key in a dictionary and it's not returning the correct output

```
def fetchAndReplace(dictionary,key,newValue):
    keys = dictionary.keys()
    for i in keys:
        if i == key:
            print dictionary[key]
            dictionary[key] = newValue
            return

        else: 
            return "Nothing"
```

When I call this one a dictionary {'x':3,'y':2}, with x for key and 6 for newValue
It returns the string nothing, which it shouldn't. I can't find anything wrong with my code so if you could point out the mistake I'm overlooking I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you understand what `for` does?

Comment: Once you `return "Nothing"` on the first `i` in the `for` loop, the loop and the function end.

Comment: What is wrong with `dictionary['x']=6`?

Comment: here, `i` in `for` is not the _index_; rather it is the _element_; means, `i` is actually the `key`

Comment: You can decrease the indentation of `else:` and `return "Nothing"`, and it will work as you would expect. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you are trying to do something along these lines:

```
def fetchAndReplace(dictionary,key,newValue):
    if key in dictionary:
        dictionary[key]=newValue
        return dictionary
    else:
        return 'Nothing' 

di=  {'x':3,'y':2}

print fetchAndReplace(di, 'z', 6)    
print fetchAndReplace(di, 'x', 6)
```

Prints:

```
Nothing
{'y': 2, 'x': 6}
```

Comment: This is closer to what I was looking for. Good call on getting rid of the for loop. I was helping a friend with his homework, and it had already been a long day so this was just going over my head for some reason. It's very obvious now though. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are `return`ing on the first iteration, so you never get to the second key.

Try this:

```
def fetchAndReplace(dictionary, key,newValue):
    keys = dictionary.keys()
    for i in keys:
        if i == key:
            dictionary[key] = newValue

    return dictionary



print fetchAndReplace({'x':3,'y':2}, 'x', 6)
```

Output:

```
{'y': 2, 'x': 6}
```

Furthermore, you can accomplish the same as your function with the `dict.update` method:

```
>>> mydict = {'x':3,'y':2}
>>> mydict.update({'x': 6})
>>> print mydict
{'y': 2, 'x': 6}
```

Hth,
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

print statements always help

```
def fetchAndReplace(dictionary,key,newValue):
    keys = dictionary.keys()
    print 'keys:', keys
    for i in keys:
        print 'i:', i, 'i == key:', i == key
        if i == key:
            print dictionary[key]
            dictionary[key] = newValue
            return

        else: 
            return "Nothing"
```

Items in a dictionary are *almost* arbitrarily *ordered*, if the conditional statement `if i == key` fails with the first item in keys, the function will return

Answer (score 0):

I'm so tempted to answer this.

You only need to delete two tab characters (or 8, if you use spaces) in order to make your code work.

**Decrease the indentation of `else:` and `return "Nothing"`**

Result:

```
def fetchAndReplace(dictionary, key, newValue):
    keys = dictionary.keys()
    for i in keys:
        if i == key:
            print dictionary[key]
            dictionary[key] = newValue
            return
    else:
        return "Nothing"

dictionary = {"x":1, "y":2}
print "The result is: " + str(fetchAndReplace(dictionary,"x",3))
print "The result is: " + str(fetchAndReplace(dictionary,"z",0))
```

This will produce:

```
1
The result is: None
The result is: Nothing
```

Why? Because by decreasing the indentation, the `else` will be attached to `for`, and according to this [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), the `else` part in  `for..else` will be executed only when the `for` loop exits normally (i.e., without `break` or `return`), which is why it will iterate over all entries, and only if the key is not found, it will return the string "Nothing". Otherwise it will return `None`, since you just have the statement `return`.

But as others had noticed, you would probably want something like this:

```
def fetchAndReplace(dictionary, key, newValue):
    result = dictionary.get(key, "Nothing")
    dictionary[key] = newValue
    return result
```

which logic is to save the original value of `dictionary[key]` in variable `result`, and if the key is not available, it will be assigned the value `Nothing`. Then you replace the value of that key with `dictionary[key] = newValue`, and then return the `result`.

Running this code:

```
dictionary = {"x":1, "y":2}
print "The result is: " + fetchAndReplace(dictionary,"x",3)
print "The result is: " + fetchAndReplace(dictionary,"z",0)
```

will produce

```
The result is: 1
The result is: Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you wanted to plan in case of there not being a dictionary. However, you already created one. Take out the return nothing.